# Does self-destruct() delete contracts data from the storage as well?

Tags: selfdestruct, gas-refund

Destroying two contracts: (1) contract A with 1 integer variable stored in it and (2) contract B with 100 integer variables stored in it, would result in the same amount of refund: 24000 gas.
So does the self-destruct clear all the contract variables and just not give the refunds for deleting them?
Or it just removes the contract reference but doesn’t remove its variables from the current EVM state?

Comment: I think there is a limit for the gas refund.. even if you theorticlay cleared more space..

Comment: https://blog.b9lab.com/selfdestruct-is-a-bug-9c312d1bb2a5

Answer (score 0):

It does clear the storage, but there is a limit for the refund you get.

> Deleting a variable refunds 15,000 gas up to a maximum of half the
> gas cost of the transaction

[https://medium.com/coinmonks/gas-optimization-in-solidity-part-i-variables-9d5775e43dde#:~:text=Ethereum%20gives%20us%20a%20gas,gas%20cost%20of%20the%20transaction](https://medium.com/coinmonks/gas-optimization-in-solidity-part-i-variables-9d5775e43dde#:%7E:text=Ethereum%20gives%20us%20a%20gas,gas%20cost%20of%20the%20transaction).

Comment: So presumably 24000 is the most refund you can get?

Comment: I assume yes, if your transaction only do "self destruct"... you can try to change something in another contract and destory the first contract within the same transaction.. so is the gas cost of the transaction is much more and probably you will refund more @MahMoo

Comment: and self destrcut is useless in most of the cases... anyone can see the data in the last block before the destruct..